# Org Mode syntax checker

Tags: emacs, org-mode

The correct syntax is this:

```
#+PROPERTY: header-args :tangle "~/.config/emacs/init.el"
```

But once, I had, instead of `header-args`, `header-aegs`.
Notice the `e` instead of `r`.
I was getting the dreaded `tangled 0 code blocks` thingy.
It took a lot of time to find the error.
My question is:

1. How to avoid this in the future?
2. Maybe there is some kind of syntax checker? Maybe `flycheck`? Maybe there is an Org Mode LSP implementation?

Comment: You can enable FlyCheck like this in emacs config file - (with-eval-after-load 'org
  (flycheck-mode))

Comment: @ByteBrawler0 But `flycheck` does not have a checker for Org Mode.

Comment: Unfortunately, this needs more than a syntax checker. Misspelling `header-aegs` does not lead to incorrect syntax: you are still defining a property, just not the one you wanted. `org-lint` does find some syntactic problems (certainly not all of them), but it does nothing for this case. But it *is* extensible, so adding a checker to it should be failrly easy. Do `C-h f org-lint` and `C-h f org-lint-add-checker` for more info.

Answer (score 1):

You might try, still alpha, the "[Literate programming using LSP and org-mode(alpha)](https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/manual-language-docs/lsp-org/)"

> `lsp-mode` provides *experimental* support for running the language servers inside of `org-mode` source blocks.
> `lsp-mode` is achieving this by obtaining the information about the source block from the source block header (language + `:tangle`) then translating the point to the LSP positions back and forth, so the language server thinks that Emacs has opened the original file.
> In order that to work, the files has to be present on the disk as well because the server expects to find them.

It states having a [org-mode integration(preview)](https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-mode/blob/c8bbdb80ed2dbfdbf55b6c4058308dab092306b5/docs/blog/2020/7.0-release.md?plain=1#L60).

> The integration is pretty raw but usable - you basically can run `lsp-mode` language intelligence over `org-mode` source block directly in the `org-mode` document.
> We have achieved that by creating virtual buffer abstraction which allows us to fake the server that the client has actually opened the real file.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It looks very interesting, and I will definitely take a look at that. But, your answer does not answer with my question.

Comment: @RefaelSheinker The idea was to answer "How to avoid this in the future?" and "Maybe there is an Org Mode LSP implementation?" with "lsp-mode experimental support for org-mode source blocks". Since there isn't a dedicated syntax checker for Org Mode in Emacs with FlyCheck, I thought this LSP module  was your best option.

Answer (score 0):

Like you noticed, `flycheck` does not have a checker for Org-mode.

You can also try @VonC 's answer, but it might not work and be tidious to set up, depending of your knowledge.

My answer would be : [Yasnippet](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Yasnippet)

If you don't use those, you should, there are a great way to develop faster and safer the way you want it. It's a "set it once and you're done" solution, so quite easy.

You can also combine this solution with good auto-completion tools, I'll let you search in those direction and I'll edit things if needed.

Comment: I know about Yasnippet. It would not help. In my case, I typed it correct the first time. The `e` and `r` mix up happened at a later date by mistake.

Comment: @RefaelSheinker you mean the e and r mix up is not your doing. It got there without you taping an e instead of a r ? Because if you use a snippet each time, ain't no problem you'll get the right letters each time

Comment: " It got there without you taping an e instead of a r ?" - No no, it was definitely I who did, but it was completely by mistake and I did not even notice how I did it.

Comment: @RefaelSheinker well in that case, using a snippet definitely solve the problem since the snippet allows you not to type the line of code.